# How do I recover income tax withheld to wrong state (where my home state has no income tax)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, withholding, georgia

I had been working as a contract to hire, working for Company A, employed by Company B. I was then directly hired by Company A, all within a tax year.

Shortly after the transition, it was found that my address had been misrecorded as being in GA (where Company A also has an office,) and as such they almost withheld GA income tax. (I am in TN, where there is no personal state income tax.)  This prompted me to check my records for Company B, and I found that they had withheld, and already remitted, quite a few months of GA Income tax.

Since I have no tax liability in my home state, I did not file a state return for the 2016 tax year, so my home state has no interest in reclaiming those funds.

Beyond calling the GA Dept. of Revenue, I am at a loss...

Clarifying Edit:
I did not work in or travel for work to GA during this employment, I did, however, travel to GA at my own expense during the interview process.

Comment: *Have* you called GA Dept of Revenue yet?

Comment: @chepner I intend to call them Monday

Comment: Does company B only operate in GA?

Comment: @hart co No, company B operates in multiple states, TN included.

Answer (score 9):

I was in a roughly similar situation: I moved from MA to WA part way through a year, paid by the same employer. 
I filed a tax return with MA (which I had to do anyways) and got a refund.

Overall it works roughly the same as it would for federal taxes withheld but not owed: to get your money refunded, you have to file a return showing that you owed zero taxes, even though you wouldn't have had to file a return otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

File a Georgia income tax form. Report Georgia taxable income: $0. Total income tax owed: $0. Tax withheld: $500 (or whatever the number is). Refund due: $500. If you're worried that they will balk at such a return, include a note explaining the mistake that was made.